# Symfony Doctrine serialize deep relationship

Tags: symfony, doctrine, entity-relationship

I'm developing an API, using symfony 4, with an entity map like this (simplified):

[image: simplified database structure]

Basically, Roles are simple containers for Operations, so it will be easier for end users to grant or deny privileges from the UI.

I know what to do to return, for example, all Accounts with their Projects, via annotations (ORM, Serializer, ...).

But I don't know how to return all Accounts with every Operation a User can do to them. I'd like a response like this:

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Account 1",
    "operations": [
        "account.list",
        "account.edit",
        "account.grant"
    ]
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Account 2",
    "operations": [
        "account.list"
    ]
}]
```

What should I do:

- Add function Account::getOperations() which calls OperationRepository::findAllByAccount() ?
- Inject OperationRepository to the controller and manually fetch Operations and assign them to a property in Accounts class not mapped by ORM?

I'm a bit lost there. Never worked with ORMs before...

Thanks.

---

Edit: this is what I would do in plain PHP (not tested):

```
public function findUserAccountsWithPermissions(int $userId)
{
    $sql = "
      SELECT
        a.id,
        a.name,
        o.code
      FROM Permission p
        INNER JOIN Account a ON a.id = p.accountId
        INNER JOIN Role_Operation ro ON ro.roleId = p.roleId
        INNER JOIN Operation o ON o.id = ro.operationId
      WHERE
        p.userId = :userId
    ";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(':userId', $userId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();

    $accounts = [];

    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        $accountId = (int)$row['id'];

        if (!isset($accounts[$accountId])) {
            $accounts[$accountId] = [
                'id'         => $accountId,
                'name'       => $row['name'],
                'operations' => [],
            ];
        }

        $accounts[$accountId]['operations'][] = $row['code'];
    }

    return array_values($accounts);
}
```

Comment: could you show the actual result and the way you are getting that result?

Comment: I added an example code of what I'd do in plain PHP.
That's my problem: I don't have a way to do this in symfony+doctrine...

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking for a query like this

> Inside PermissionRepository(I asume you have all the mapping info)

```
public function findOperationAccountForUser(User $user)
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p');

        $qb->leftJoin('p.role', 'r')
            ->leftJoin('r.operations', 'op')
            ->leftJoin('p.account', 'a')
            ->where($qb->expr()->eq('p.user', ':user'))
            ->setParameter('user', $user)
            ->select('op.code, op.name,r.name, a.name,...');//or exclude for select all fields

        return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();//or arrayResult as you want
    }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: This approach has some drawbacks.
If I return Permission objects, then I'll have to classify them at every account. So, for each Permission, ORM will do query to fetch Account, and another query to fetch Operations. Too many queries for a task that'll be executed at every request.
If I return an array with just the fields I need (Operation.code), then what's the point of an ORM, besides simple queries?
We're thinking of dropping ORM, just use DBAL, and write our queries efficiently.

Comment: @Albert what ever query you would ever write in SQL, can be implemented with ORM, I just gave you an example of how should it be according to your question if you want an array(which is better) you use arrayResult instead of Result(as I said in my answer). In the other hand if you only need some fields you only need to be specific in the select. I think the query is very simple, only has three join. You also could change the query and do it in user or operation repository but would be the same three joins to compare the user and extract the fields from account,operation and user. Give it a try